# Ionic 3 Livereload not working on Android device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

In one of my projects where the `--livereload` flag was working , suddenly the feature is not working but I see Launch Success message on my console.

After launching the app on my android device the Splash screen stays on infinitely and then a message appears as

```
Application Error
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 
(http://192.168 .0.102:8100/)
```

My config XML has the following :

```
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="300000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

So it specifically mentions `loadUrlTimeoutValue as 700000` - but that did not have a positive effect !

Then I added an **Inbound Rule** to my Windows Firewall to allow specifically the following ports : `8100, 35729, 53703` as these appeared on the console with the following command:

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload --consolelogs
```

```
> ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 
--dev-logger-port 53703 --consolelogs --nobrowser --iscordovaserve 
--platform android --target cordova

[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.1
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  watch started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  build dev started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  clean started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  clean finished in less than 1 ms
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  copy started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  deeplinks started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  deeplinks finished in less than 1 ms
[app-scripts] [19:00:36]  transpile started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:41]  transpile finished in 5.10 s
[app-scripts] [19:00:41]  preprocess started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:41]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[app-scripts] [19:00:41]  webpack started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:41]  copy finished in 5.29 s
[app-scripts] [19:00:45]  webpack finished in 3.63 s
[app-scripts] [19:00:45]  sass started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  sass finished in 1.00 s
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  postprocess started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  postprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  lint started ...
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  build dev finished in 9.92 s
[app-scripts] [19:00:46]  watch ready in 9.98 s

[INFO] Development server running!
```

This also did not help ..

Finally I added the following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

that too did not solve the issue.

I am stuck with the above problem - I will highly appreciate if any fellow devs could get me out of this soup!!

Thanks in advance.

#### My Ionic Info is as follows:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, 
                           cordova- plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 7
```

Comment: What is the `cordova-android` and the `cordova` version?

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu Thanks for your quick response. I have added the info in the main description. Please take a look.

Comment: `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />` Can you try change it to `true`?

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu Ok I will give it a try and let you know .. but what could be the logic behind it ? Note that the same config XML was live reloading the app on my device correctly till last week.

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu  I have just tested with your suggested edit. Unfortunately that did not work. The issue stays as before.

Comment: Have you double checked that you're in the same network and you can reach your dev laptop/computer from your android phone?

Comment: @Phonolog yes absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

although I didn't face the exactly issue you're having, I also had a hard time trying to run liveload on an Android device with a Ionic 3 project.
Below is what I did to solve it.

**Installing dependencies**

npm cache clean –force

delete node_modules (if it exists)

delete packagelock.js (if it exists)

npm install

**Remove cordova platform android with the following command**

ionic cordova platforms rm android

**Add android platform**

ionic cordova platforms add android@8.0.0

**Fixing error**

You need to install a cordova plugin to fix the dependency that is missing. You can do so by applying the following command:

cordova plugin add cordova-support-android-plugin

**With your android device connected to your pc and both connected on the same Wi-Fi run the following command**

ionic cordova run android -l